# As soon as I start dragging an element with jQuery UI, the text wraps in some cases

Tags: jquery-ui

I am writing an application that allows a user to drag elements from one list to another in the horizontal direction.  I made a [jsfiddle for it.](https://jsfiddle.net/RufusVS/wgxb9xu9/1/) based on a jQuery example:

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 50px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Larger Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">I3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Humongous Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, some elements wrap text as soon as I start to drag them.  Not all of them, though.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I would try to set the with (and height?) of the element as soon as you start dragging and remove them on drop

Comment: Even if I set the draggable elements to a fixed width, the text still wraps, only now it goes outside the boundary of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, which I don't find completely satisfactory, but if I replace the spaces in the draggable divs with &nbsp; it prevents the wrap.  The updated [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/RufusVS/wgxb9xu9/2/), which shows two sets of draggables, one with spaces, one with &nbsp; as seen with these two rows:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Larger Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">I3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Humongous Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item&nbsp;1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Larger&nbsp;Item&nbsp;2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">I3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item&nbsp;4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Humongous&nbsp;Item&nbsp;5</li>
</ul>
```

The highlighted ones in the second row don't wrap when dragged.  Not the best solution, but workable.